# How to record x days in a loop with ZoneMinder?

Tags: zoneminder

I would like to keep a trail of 7 days in ZoneMinder. Therfore I would like to set the record mode to: "record" (to be recording all the time). How can I get ZoneMinder to store no more than 7 days?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for a "recordig loop" is the "purge when full filter" in ZoneMinder: 
http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#How_can_I_stop_ZoneMinder_filling_up_my_disk.3F ([via](http://www.zoneminder.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=22117))

With this filter you can define the criteria for deleting old events, e.g. "when partition is 75% full", etc. Very versatile tool!